# Compressing the Data

Tags: python

```py
def compress_data(word):
   a=1
   index=0
   compressed_word = ""
   while index<len(word):
           if (word[index]==word[index+1]):
            a=+1
            temp_letter=word.index 
            index=index+1
           elif word[index]!=word[index+1]:
            temp_letter2=word[index]
            index=index+1
           compressed_word=a+temp_letter+temp_letter2
            
   print(compressed_word)
word=input('Enter Word:')
compress_data(word)
```

I need to compress the data in python. For example: Like this:

- input: 'aaaeebdddd' output: '3a2eb4d'
- input: 'PPTTTMgggEE' output: '2P3TM3g2E'
- input: 'GHJ' output: 'GHJ'
- input: ' ' output: ' '

How can I write this in python?

Comment: I know.  There are many wrong. For example:     if (word[index]==word[index+1]):
IndexError: string index out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def compress_data(word):

    previous = ""
    letter_counter = 1
    compressed_word = ""
   
    for letter in word:
        if letter == previous:
            letter_counter += 1
        else:
            compressed_word += str(letter_counter) + previous if letter_counter > 1 else previous
            letter_counter = 1
        previous = letter
    compressed_word += str(letter_counter) + previous if letter_counter > 1 else previous
    return compressed_word


word=input('Enter Word:')
print(compress_data(word))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regex...

```
>>> re.sub(r'((.)\2*)(?=\2)', lambda m: str(len(m.group(1)) + 1), 'PPTTTMgggEE')
'2P3TM3g2E'
```

Answer (score 1):

`itertools.groupby` is perfect for the job. It creates subiterators every time a condition in an interator changes. By default, that's every time an iterated value changes from the previous value.

```
import itertools

def compress_data(word):
    result = []
    # generates subiterator `group` when char in word changes
    for key, group in itertools.groupby(word):
        # iterates and counts the like-valued characters in the group
        count = sum(1 for _ in group)
        if count > 1:
            result.append(str(count))
        result.append(key)
    return "".join(result)

tests = (
    ('aaaeebdddd', '3a2eb4d'),
    ('PPTTTMgggEE', '2P3TM3g2E'),
    ('GHJ', 'GHJ'),
    ('', '') )

print('worked', 'word', 'want', 'got')
for word, want in tests:
    got = compress_data(word)
    print(want==got, word, want, got)
```

Running it shows

```
~/tmp$ python test.py
worked word want got
True aaaeebdddd 3a2eb4d 3a2eb4d
True PPTTTMgggEE 2P3TM3g2E 2P3TM3g2E
True GHJ GHJ GHJ
True
```